# cannot download and install plugins in netbeans ide 8.0.1

Tags: java, ide, netbeans-8, java-ee-8, netbeans-plugins

Getting following error while trying downloading or adding plugins:
Unable to connect to the NetBeans Distribution because of Zero sized file reported at http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/8.0.1/uc/final/distribution/catalog.xml.gz?unique=NB_EXTIDE_JAVA0e42fa219-4cc3-47db-b798-6ca2701de51e_9c17002b-5e94-40a8-a732-d2f3be3f432d

It also says:
Check your proxy settings or try again later. The server may be unavailable at the moment. You may also want to make sure that your firewall is not blocking network traffic.

[dialog box showing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnZXB.png)

I googled for solutions and tried adding netbeans to windows firewall so that it may pass through it, turning off windows firewall (which was recommended as last option) and also, tried changing proxy settings but the issue remains same.

Comment: There is no support for NetBeans 8.0.1 anywhere. It is a very old release which was created before NetBeans migrated to Apache. From [the archive download page for NetBeans](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/archive/index.html#:~:text=Older%20Apache%20NetBeans,March%204%2C%202022.), the oldest release that you can download is NetBeans 9. That page states: _"While Oracle distributed previous versions of NetBeans bundled with their JDK for a while this is no longer the case. There is no official source anymore to download previous versions"_. Why do you need to use NetBeans 8.x at all?

Comment: i got some tutorials from someone and its setup was there so I thought of using the same

Comment: OK. In that case just find a newer tutorial. There have been over 20 releases of NetBeans since 8.0.1. And even if you could get everything up and running, you couldn't use any release of Java > 8. The download for the current release of NetBeans (18) [is here](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb18/index.html).